# How do I query a website URL from within shinyapp and display the webpage output in shiny

Tags: r, iframe, shiny, shinyapps

I'd like for users of my app to be able to textInput a gene (eg. alcama) and then view the website output within the app. I am running the app locally.

[This](https://zfin.org/action/expression/results?rows=25&geneField=alcama&authorField=&anatomyTermIDs=&anatomyTermNames=&searchTerm=&includeSubstructures=true&_includeSubstructures=on&startStageId=ZFS%3A0000001&endStageId=ZFS%3A0000044&assayName=&onlyWildtype=true&_onlyWildtype=on&_onlyReporter=on&_onlyFiguresWithImages=on&journalType=ALL) is the website I am trying to access, although ideally I'd be able to have the textInput search in the search bar [image] although I think that's going to be far more complicated than I'm imagining as the gene's are all ID'd eg. https://zfin.org/ZDB-GENE-990415-30 rather than using the conventional name (alcama)

I have posted the relevant snippet of my code to attempt this, however it's just resulting in a blank box within the app when I type in eg. alcama.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(title = "Lab Data",
                           sidebarPanel(
                             selectInput("GEcelltype", "Choose a Cell Type:", 
                                         choices = c("MG", "CMZ", "RPE", "Cones", 'RGC', 'Whole Eye')),
                             
                             textInput(inputId = 'GEgene', label = "Plot Expression, please type gene (all lowercase)", value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = 'EG: alcama'), 
                             sliderInput("min", "Select Minimum Expression Cutoff",
                                         min = 0, max = 5, value = 0
                             ),
                             
                             
                           ),#sidebarpanel
                mainPanel(
                  fluidRow( htmlOutput("frame")),
                ) #mainpanel
                           
)# fluidpage

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({ 
    query <- input$GEgene
    test <<- paste0("https://zfin.org/action/expression/results?rows=25&geneField=",query,"&authorField=&anatomyTermIDs=&anatomyTermNames=&searchTerm=&includeSubstructures=true&_includeSubstructures=on&startStageId=ZFS%3A0000001&endStageId=ZFS%3A0000044&assayName=&onlyWildtype=true&_onlyWildtype=on&_onlyReporter=on&_onlyFiguresWithImages=on&journalType=ALL")
  })
  output$frame <- renderUI({
    input$GEgene
    my_test <- tags$iframe(src=test, height=600, width=900)
    print(my_test)
    my_test
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This website has `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`, which means they don't allow you to embed their content in an `iframe`. You can search their documents to see if they have special URLs to allow you embed. If not, there is nothing you can do.